# React table with static header on browser scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, react-table

Is there a table component for react, which would have fixed header while browser scrollbar scrolls it's long body? (The table height grows as user clicks "Load more"). Here's a code sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/rm0x6lmypm
The table header should remain static on browser scroll.

Comment: first results from google:  https://henrybuilt.github.io/react-sticky-table/ , https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme

Comment: Add your code directly to the question

Comment: @Zoe it's ~700 lines of code

Comment: So? You still have to add it to your question, and make an MCVE assuming you haven't already

Comment: check out this npm package [react-sticky-table-thead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table-thead)

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I have made some horrible css changes, now it seems to work as needed:
https://codesandbox.io/s/18kqoyjq8j
Basically I added styles to `react-table` as follows:

```
.ReactTable {
  margin-top: 74px;
}

.ReactTable .rt-tbody {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.ReactTable .rt-thead {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 17px);
  height: 31px;
}
```

So the table header is now fixed under the page header and we can use browser scrollbar to scroll table's body.

Comment: Sometimes you need to `fake it` as you did :)  Sounds like a reasonable workaround 

Comment: check out this npm package [react-sticky-table-thead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky-table-thead)

Comment: the header should not be fixed on horizontal scroll